# Assumption while Solving a system of linear ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

To solve the following matrix equation:$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{\epsilon}\\
\dot{\delta}
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{f_x^*} &\dot{f_y^*}\\
\dot{g_x^*} &\dot{f_y^*}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon\\
\delta
\end{pmatrix}
$$, [this link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Applied_Mathematics/Mathematical_Biology_(Chasnov)/01%3A_Population_Dynamics/1.04%3A_The_Lotka-Volterra_Predator-Prey_Model) says that we assume $\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon\\
\delta
\end{pmatrix} = e^{\lambda t}\textbf{v}$. What's the reason for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It is a short cut once you know that the matrix is diagonalizable i.e it can be written in the form $M=UDU^{-1}$, where D is a diagonal matrix and the columns of $U$ are eigenvectors of $M$. Then the equations have the form

$$U^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{\epsilon}\\
\dot{\delta}
\end{pmatrix}
=DU^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon\\
\delta
\end{pmatrix}$$

Which is two first order DE's of the form

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\lambda y$$

Comment: What if its not diagonalisable?

Comment: There are extra terms of the form $t^ne^{\lambda t}$. For example, if the matrix has a double eigenvalue $\lambda$ and then only one eigenvector v, $e^{\lambda t}v$ and  $te^{\lambda t}v$ will be solutions. In your link, the matrix is assumed diagonal. See this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4428741/can-systems-of-linear-odes-be-solved-when-their-matrix-is-not-diagonalizable

Comment: Sorry, that should be $te^{\lambda t}w$ where $(M-\lambda I)w = v$, is also a solution.