# Differential equations with repeated roots but different eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

For the following differential equation: $$x' = \begin{bmatrix}3&-1&-1\\1&1&-1\\1&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}x,$$ I only get two eigenvalues: $r = 1$ and $r = 2$. Generally, I would find two eigenvectors for the repeated root, $r = 2$, but that value gives me two eigenvectors to start with. When I used an online calculator, it said to use the two given eigenvectors and don't find one. Is this always the case because my found eigenvector is a little different.

Thank you

Comment: Similar situation with [(3,2,4), (2,2,0), (4,2,3)]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also, I believe that this matrix is not diagonalizable, so you will have to compute its Jordan form and find a generalized eigenvector for $r=2$.

Comment: the matrix is not diagonalizable! https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5B%5B3%2C-1%2C-1%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C-1%5D%2C%5B1%2C-1%2C-1%5D%5D see my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4676411/542895 to adapt to your system